# Call a particular PHP Function In same page using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, file-upload, image-uploading

I am creating a widget using PHP, Jquery and Ajax that can upload and crop an Image. When we select an image, and submit the form. The following code is executed, which uploads the image:

```
<?php

    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
            if(strlen($name))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats) && $size<(1024*1024))
                        {
                            $actual_image_name = time().substr($txt, 5).".".$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                                {
                                    $image="<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' id=\"photo\" style='max-width:500px' >";

                                }
                            else
                                echo "failed";
                        }
                    else
                        echo "Invalid file formats..!";                 
                }
            else
                echo "Please select image..!";
        }
?>
```

While submitting form, the page is getting refreshed. I want to do this without page refresh.

Suppose that if I put the above PHP code in a PHP function, without using
  `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Then, is there any way, to call the PHP function using AJAX.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Have a look at [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), And combine it for `$('form').on('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();$.ajax('url-to-post-to',dataObject)})

Comment: @Tim I am not submitting the form, I want to do it on the when the file gets selected

Comment: Than you're looking for `$('file-select').on('change',function(){});`?

Comment: One thing you need to know: You cannot call PHP from JS, PHP is transformed to HTML and the client(browser) doesn't know anything about this.. You can however send data to the php-file via AJAX and let it save/return the stuff you need..

Comment: @Tim Thanks a lot. Then I guess, I should try something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I was looking for something that can submit a PHP form via AJAX as soon as the image is selected and upload the image. I found this code,

```
$('#photoimg').live('change', function(){ 
     $("#preview").html('');
     $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#preview'
    }).submit();    
});
```

Here, *photoimg* is the ID of input type file, *imageform* is the ID of the form, and *preview* is the ID of div, where the preview is going to be displayed. When the file is selected, the **change** event is fired and the form is submitted. You can refer [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if($_POST)
```

to check instead of

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Comment: I am not submitting the form, I want to do it on the when the file gets selected

Answer (score 0):

Hey as you want to upload files and dont want to refresh page when you select files.You can use jquery's `$.ajax or $.post` I prefers `$.ajax`. In that you have to give appropriate parameters to ajax call.In url parameter you have to give name of php file i.e your above php script.and also you have to do some changes in your php script,as you are not going to post you have to remove condition 
`if(isset($_POST['submit']))`
if you get success,in ajax call you get result.You can use `json` to return result from php script to your jquery,and parse it in jquery.
And also as [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540447/tim) said you have to use change() in your jquery because you dont want to use post by clicking any button.Refer this
[link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)